# How to calculate work experience in a company from a certain hire_date to getdate() expressed in Years-Months-Days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, julian-date

I have an employee table which stores in a column the dates employees were hired. I am trying to calculate their work experience (seniority) from the *hire_date* to *getdate()?* And lets say I would like to store this "Work_experience" column in a view alongside a Name and ID , so It would always be updated to the current date.

I have seen various ideas from other users, most of them using 2 variables (inputs) and a piece of query that would calculate the difference between them, but most of them don't account for **leap years**, or have other deficiencies.

I was thinking to do this more accurately using a math formula and I came across this one on multiple websites:

```
f(y,m,d) = 365*y+ y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + (153*m- 457)/5 + d - 306
date_diff(y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2) = f(y1,m1,d1) - f(y2,m2,d2)
```

Using this one would only return the total number of days and the challenge is to translate this into x-Years y-Months z-Days and store it in a column using SQL.

If there are any suggestions/hints on how to calculate the work_experience either with the math formula, or with any other approach I would be very grateful on you answers.

Comment: Why not just calculate the value in days?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because the value expressed in Years-Months-Days, will be later on displayed in a employee bio, and I need it in this specific format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what intervals you need. Possible way
is to use Sql server date arithmetic. For example

```
-- input params
declare @dt datetime ='2017-06-07'
declare @now datetime = getdate();

-- output
declare @y int,  @m int,  @d int;

-- compute it
declare @base datetime;
set @y = datediff(Year, @dt, @now);
if (dateadd(Year, @y, @dt) > @now) 
   set @y -=1;
set @base= dateadd(Year, @y, @dt);
set @m = datediff(month, @base, @now);
if (dateadd(month, @m, @base) > @now)
   set @m -=1;
set @base = dateadd(month, @m, @base);   
set @d = datediff(day, @base, @now);
-- A number of years, months and days in the @dt..@now interval
select @y, @m, @d;
```

You can create a TVF or something using the idea.